# Play! FrameWork: I'm having a problem uploading an image to my server

Tags: scala, file-upload, vuejs2, playframework

i hope someone can help me. I use following Code snippet to upload an image to my server (This is copied from here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaFileUpload

````
```def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
    request.body
        .file("file")
        .map { picture =>
        
        val filename    = Paths.get(picture.filename).getFileName
        val fileSize    = picture.fileSize
        val contentType = picture.contentType

        // Test Print
        print("content Type: "+contentType)
        print("filename: "+filename)
        print("filesize: "+fileSize)

        picture.ref.copyTo(Paths.get(s"/tmp/picture/$filename"), replace = true)
        Ok("File uploaded")
        }
        .getOrElse {
        null //TODO: changeme
        }
    }```
````

I checked filename, filesize and content-type with my print methods and it seems to be working..

But i always get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: xsbti.BasicVirtualFileRef cannot be cast to java.io.File
        at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.$anonfun$sourceMap$1(PlayReload.scala:70)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues.get(MapLike.scala:261)
        at play.runsupport.Reloader.$anonfun$findSource$1(Reloader.scala:552)
        at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:271)
        at play.runsupport.Reloader.findSource(Reloader.scala:551)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1$$anon$2.sourceOf(DevServerStart.scala:174)
        at play.core.SourceMapper.$anonfun$sourceFor$1(ApplicationProvider.scala:22)
        at play.core.SourceMapper.$anonfun$sourceFor$1$adapted(ApplicationProvider.scala:22)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.$anonfun$find$1(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.$anonfun$find$1$adapted(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:53)
```

Some hard facts:

- Fronted: Vue.js 2.6.12
- Backend: Play!Framework with Scala (2.12.8) and sbt version 4.0.0
- This is my inputfield in vue:
   `<input type="file" ref="file" @change="onSelect" />`

I really hope someone can help me:). If u need more information to help, just ask me:)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/10486), Play may have problems with certain SBT versions and vice versa.

[This workaround](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/10486#issuecomment-763298623) might work for you.

This issue was also [patched](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/10486#issuecomment-816476096) for Play 2.8.8 so try updating to latest version.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem!